# Android Edittext start edit from i click (anywhere)

Tags: android, onclick, android-edittext

I am a newbie.
I search so long,but not found the answer.

There is my Questions.

picture : http://imgur.com/UZjnPKF

click EditText Aera anywhere and start edit there

Plz,help me

Update 2015/08/06 PM14:40(GMT+8)

hi, i put a new picture to explanation my Questions

here: http://imgur.com/C5P3h5M

thank the comment, now I'm learn text watcher .

Comment: Didn't understand your question

Comment: My English is pretty basic, please don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Ilja KO said is true so I'm just going to post it even if it's really bad practice. Add an EditText.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:gravity="top"/>
```

In your onCreate function get the EditText and set it with as many spaces as you want:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
//Add as many spaces as is needed
editText.setText("                 ");
```

Comment: Well he could fill it with white spaces and position the cursor then at the point the edit text was clicked and use text watcher to delete a whitespace when the user types something or add one if a char is deleted...well i must admit this is a rather nasty hack but that would do the trick :)